# is telling the truth necassary under this cicumstance?

Tags: sin

if a person lied about committing adultery when he never did it.
to boast about it to people.

does he need to go around all the people and tell  them that he was **just lying?**
cz either way he just looks BAD.
is it necessary?

Comment: It would be even worse if that person (hoping it is not you) had been shouting around with whom he did the adultery.

Comment: He didn't. Th conversation was closed. And it's okay now. So does he need to bring it up again?

Comment: Allah knows all, and, sometimes, people are best of if they don't know all. Imagine the damage if someone goes around telling to *not have illegal intercourse* with XXX.